# Move files to HDFS using Spring XD

Tags: spring-xd

How to move the files from local disk to HDFS using Spring XD.

I do not want contents , but to move whole file for archival which saves the file with original name and content.

Here is what i have tried

stream create --name fileapple --definition "file --mode=ref --dir=/Users/dev/code/open/learnspringxd/input --pattern=apple*.txt | WHATTODOHERE"

I can see now with reference the file names with full path are made available , how to move that to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#csv-hdfs) which imports data from files to HDFS as a batch job and check if that fits your requirement. You can also check `file | hdfs` as a stream if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

example like below will load the file from data folder to HDFS and save the file by date folders(if there are multi records with different date) which by the record column named LastModified, the data file is a json file separate by lines.

```
file --mode=ref --dir=/Users/dev/code/open/learnspringxd/input --pattern=apple*.txt  | hdfs --directory=/user/file_folder --partitionPath=path(dateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd',#jsonPath(payload,'$.LastModified'),'yyyy-MM-dd')) --fileName=output_file_name_prefix --fsUri=hdfs://HDFShostname.company.com:8020 --idleTimeout=30000
```